# Почему серверы (сайты) Tor анонимны?

Tags: сервер, ip, tor

Если сайт поднят на каком-то сервере, то этот сервер статичный, то есть должен иметь статичный IP, не так ли? Когда кто-то подключается к .onion сайту, он проходит через входной узел, средний узел и выходным узлом как раз будет этот .onion сайт, то есть внутри сети tor все зашифровано (если не обращаться к сайтам clear-нета), но IP все-равно должен быть видимым. Почему тогда сайты Tor анонимны?

Comment: Потому что там строятся два встречных тоннеля, которые "встречаются" на случайном узле.

Comment: А как работает DNS запрос? DNS запрос идет тоже через tor?

Comment: А DNS запрос никак не идёт, зона .onion в DNS не представлена. Как и .i2p